# Undetected .runtimeconfig.json when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET application to Elastic Beanstalk's .NET Core on Linux. When I upload the code, I get the following error:

```
Instance deployment: Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix. The deployment failed.
```

The issue is that I have such a file in the root of the zip file I'm uploading. When I upload the sample application it works, but when I upload my own, it does not. Here are the contents of my `Project.runtimeconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified the issue: I was zipping up one level too high. Rather than zip the folder that contained the `.runtimeconfig.json` file, you need to zip up the contents of that folder directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. add runtime config to your .csproj or write your own json file:

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

2. generate the aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json file:

```json
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "deployments": {

    "aspNetCoreWeb": [
      {
        "name": "<<your app name>>",
        "parameters": {
          "appBundle": ".",
          "iisPath": "/",
          "iisWebSite": "Default Web Site"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

3. publish your app and generate your bundle (.zip file):

```
$ dotnet publish -o bundle
```

Your app bundle (.zip file) must contain the files 'appname.runtimeconfig.json' and 'aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json' in the root folder in order to deploy successfully.

Ex:

```
> bundle.zip
   > app.dll
   > app.runtimeconfig.json
   > aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
```

note that the prop "appBundle": "." in 'aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json' indicates the files in the same folder.

*Sorry if I misspelling it, feel free to correct me.*